# Replication Distribution issue after installed SP3

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, replication

I have a system with replication distribution.

We have been asked to upgrade SQL Server 2016 to SP3. Now I saw issues surfaced out.

1. There are 2 servers in the `sys.server` table. This is what we have when running:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM sys.servers
   ```

   [image]

2. Before upgrading to SP3, deploy the system, I saw that in the "snapshot agent" records in table `MSsnapshot_agents`, all are associated with `server_id -> 0` (`VM1` which is the server name).
3. But **after** upgrading to SP3, deployed the same system again on a brand-new server environment, no code changes, the "snapshot agent" records in table `MSsnapshot_agents`  all are associated with `server_id -> 1` (`repl_distributor`).

Can you please help me understand how the table `MSsnapshot_agents` is configured? Why upgraded to SP3, the records now are associated with different values (from previous "0" (`VM1`) to "1" (`repl_distributor`))?

This change breaks the software system deployment.

I scanned the code base (very large), and I did not find any code do `INSERT` operation to this table `MSsnapshot_agents`. So I guess those records might be added/inserted by some system configurations triggered by the software system I maintained.